# Broadcom Wireless Issues in Lubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, drivers, lubuntu, broadcom, firmware

I recently installed Lubuntu 14.04 on my parents' old laptop, and I've been having a super difficult time getting the Broadcom card up and running. I've been following this thread: [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

...but I'm still stuck.

`lspci -vnn | grep Network` showed:

```
06:05.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4306 802.11b/g Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:4320] (rev 02)
```

`iwconfig` showed:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

I've installed `b43-firmware-installer` and `b43-fwcutter` and also the `linux-firmware-nonfree` package. At boot, I keep getting a b43-phy0 error, so I tried `sudo rmmod b43`, and I got:

```
rmmod: ERROR: Module b43 is not currently loaded
```

I also tried:

```
    dmesg | grep b43
    [   17.318405] b43legacy-phy0: Broadcom 4306 WLAN found (core revision 4)
    [   17.384870] b43legacy-phy0: Loading firmware b43legacy/ucode4.fw
    [   18.046777] b43legacy ssb0:0: Direct firmware load failed with error -2
    [   18.046785] b43legacy ssb0:0: Falling back to user helper
    [   18.047858] b43legacy-phy0 ERROR: Firmware file "b43legacy/ucode4.fw" not
    found or load failed.
    [   18.047965] b43legacy-phy0 ERROR: You must go to
    http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43#devicefirmware and download the
    correct firmware (version 3).
```

I went to url it told me to, but it didn't tell me to do anything I haven't already tried.

Any help and/or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @ubfan1 Thanks a lot! That fixed it. We can consider this thread closed, I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 4306 hardware, according to http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43 takes the b43legacy driver, NOT the b43 driver.  Try the firmware-b43legacy-installer package to see if that gets you the correct firmware (ucode4.fw) and puts it into /lib/firmware/b43legacy.  It looks like you are pulling in the correct driver, it just doesn't have the correct firmware.